# powershell single switch parameter only

Tags: powershell

Providing I have a three switch parameters

```posh
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false] [switch] $i,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false] [switch] $ir,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$false] [switch] $iur
)
```

and only **ONE** of them is allowed, what is the best way to do this? If I use what's above, all three switches can be added as a parameter on a single call (undesirable).

```posh
> invoke-aspnetregiis -i -ir -iur # bad
```

I originally used a `ValidateSet` on a `[string]`

```posh
[parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValidateSet('-i', '-ir', '-iur'))] [string] $arg
```

but then the call looks funny

```posh
invoke-aspnetregiis '-i' # notice the single quotes.
```

I prefer it too read

```posh
invoke-aspnetregiis -i # to mimic the native call
```

The best I've come up with so far is to use `ParameterSetNames`

```posh
[parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='i')] [switch] $i,
[parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='ir')] [switch] $ir,
[parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='iur')] [switch] $iur,

switch($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
    'i'   {$argument = '-i'}
    'ir'  {$argument = '-ir'}
    'iur' {$argument = '-iur'}
    default {$argument = '-i'}
}
```

essentially making the actual switch irrelevant.

Is there a better way to accomplish this in Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter sets is what you'd normally use for something like this. If you name the parameter sets after the parameters you can even simplify passing the parameter to the actual command you're calling:

```psh
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='-i')]
Param(
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='-i',Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$i,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='-ir',Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$ir,
  [Parameter(ParameterSetName='-iur',Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$iur
)

& yourcommand $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

There are, of course, other options as well, like building your own logic for ensuring that just one out of the three parameters is provided:

```psh
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$i,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$ir,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][Switch]$iur
)

if (1 -ne $i.IsPresent + $ir.IsPresent + $iur.IsPresent) {
  'Usage: script.ps1 {-i|-ir|iur}'
  exit 1
}
```

However, as @mikez pointed out in the comments, the command/script help will not automatically show that the parameters cannot be used in conjunction with each other:

```
PS C:\> .\test_paramset.ps1 -?
test_paramset.ps1 [-a] [<CommonParameters>]
test_paramset.ps1 [-b] [<CommonParameters>]
test_paramset.ps1 [-c] [<CommonParameters>]

PS C:\> .\test_no_paramset.ps1 -?
test_no_paramset.ps1 [-a] [-b] [-c] [<CommonParameters>]
```

thus making the alternative approach a little less user-friendly.

Comment: interesting condition approach, can't say I've every seen anything like it :)

Comment: Certainly you can do this, however it does make the help less useful. All the switches appear in the same parameter set so they seem like they can be used in combination, but they can't be.

Comment: so you're saying the parameterset as I've defined is a more accurate approach? It's sorta what I'm thinking anyways.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Not more accurate in terms of functionality, but in terms of documentation. `Get-Help` for the parameter set approach will show that the parameters cannot be used in conjunction, whereas `Get-Help` for the alternative approach I lined out above won't, so you'd need to provide that information yourself, e.g. via [comment-based help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847834.aspx) sections for each parameter.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell also if you used the `param` in conjunction with your parametersets PowerShell will throw and error thus preventing misuse when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

the best can be use the validate scrip

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateScript({-not ($descendente -or $aleatorio )})][Switch]$ascendente, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateScript({-not ($ascendente -or $aleatorio  )})][Switch]$descendente, 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateScript({-not ($ascendente -or $descendente)})][Switch]$aleatorio
```

so powershell will throw the error

Comment: this is a valid approach and I'll +1 it, however a ParameterSet will actually prevent autocomplete from looking at the other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the ParameterSetName usage makes the switches irrelevant. They are how the user picked the mode in the first place.

You don't have to use the same name for the ParameterSetName as the switch name.

You don't have to use `$argument` and can just use the switch name if you cant.

You can just use the switch name and ignore `ParameterSetName` (since powershell has ensured you only get one switch among the sets already).

You could also manually validate the arguments given if you wanted to.

I don't know of any other way (but I'm not a powershell expert either).